# Solubility of alcohols in non-polar solvents

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, solvents, intermolecular-forces

The solubility of an alcohol in a non-polar solvent (like hexane) increases with size of the alcohol, as the non-polar chain increases. However, as the chain keeps increasing, will the solubility eventually start to drop because the molecule becomes too large?

Comment: Yes, I expect so.

Comment: Think about the extreme. I wouldn't expect polyethylene to be very soluble in hexane.

Comment: @Max. The problem is related to alcohols, not to  alcanes

Comment: @Maurice - The terminal -OH group wouldn't make any significant difference in solubility in hexane between a extremely long alkane and a extremely long n-alcohol.

Comment: Actually, polyethylene is soluble in organic solvents such as toluene, xylene, and mehylene chloride at slightly elevated temperatures. You may have even noticed this if you tried to wash a weigh dish with an organic non-polar solvent. This is an interesting question, but I would infer that the length of the chain would not have a significant effect on the solubility of an alcohol of high chain length.

Comment: Edit: Weight boats are actually made of polystyrene, but the same idea applies

Comment: @EliJones Like with solubility of ions, wouldn't the solubility decrease as the chain length increases? Why do big molecules like polystyrene dissolve in non-polar solvents? Does the polymer chain break into smaller chains or something along those lines?